# Can G-tag with the same name function properly for GA4, when it's setup within a GTM-container with the same ID?

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

I had a G-tag on my website Dwellics.com (G-410QZL9TLN), and GA4 was getting a data stream from it. Then I added a GTM-container tag, removed the G-tag from the website code and added G-410QZL9TLN as a tag for the GTM-container within the GTM account. I added a Regex table for Content Groups as a variable for this same G-tag. Now my GA4 shows some Content Groups, but not all, if shows "(not set") for a half of pages. And the standard report "Pages and screens: Page title and screen class" starts showing just 1 line after I switch back to it from the report by the Content Groups, so I cannot see what pages were actually visited on that day.

I tried to disconnect G-tag from GA4 and reconnect to the G-tag inside the container with a different name, and it looked like working, but then the number of visitors dropped to 0 until I re-connected and renamed everything back.

Should I rename the G-tag inside the container and add a new stream with it?
Or should I just create a different tag just for the reporting by the Content Groups?

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to remove of gtag is to remove all source code from the site pages, and enter the measurementID (like G-VN0H9D97XX) in the tag manager in the configuration tag.
The data stream for analytics can be left unchanged. The key for linking data from different sources (g-tag, GTM, manual send) is only measurementID.